# How to make cheerio not to self-close tags?

Tags: javascript, html, abstract-syntax-tree, cheerio

The output of this code with `cheerio`:

```
  <div id="some"></div>
```

Returns as self-closing tag:

```
 <div id="some"/>
```

Is it possible to change that behavior (self-closing)? I don't want to use that.

I tried those options but doesn't seems that affect the output:

```
  { decodeEntities: false, xmlMode: true, recognizeSelfClosing: false },
```

Is any other solution maybe available?

```
import "./styles.css";
import { CheerioAPI, load } from "cheerio";

console.clear();

const doc = load(
  `
  <div id="some"></div>
`,
  { decodeEntities: false, xmlMode: true, recognizeSelfClosing: false },
  false
);

console.log({
  after: doc.html({
    decodeEntities: false,
    xmlMode: true,
    recognizeSelfClosing: false
  })
});
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-mestorf-mi15iz?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `xmlMode:true` you need to set `xmlMode:false` and remove `recognizeSelfClosing: false`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { CheerioAPI, load } from "cheerio";

console.clear();

const doc = load(
  `
  <div id="some"></div>
`,
  { decodeEntities: false, xmlMode: true, recognizeSelfClosing: false },
  false
);

console.log({
  after: doc.html({
    decodeEntities: false,
    xmlMode: false
  })
});
```

This will give you the output in the console as

```
{after: "
  <div id="some"></div>
"}
```